# Design of MAC unit (dsp processors) using VHDL

Tags: vhdl

My project is design of 32bit MAC(Multiply and Accumlate) unit using reversible logic. For the project , i have designed 32bit mulitplier and 64 bit adder using reversible logic. Now, in the next step i want to design  a 64 bit accumlator which takes the value from the adder  and stores it and adds with the previous value present in it. I am not getting any idea how to design Accumlator.
Please help in completion of my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic VHDL accumulator can be implemented in only a few lines of code. How *you* decide to implement it, and any additional features necessary are going to depend on your specific requirements.

For example:

- Are the inputs signed or unsigned?
- What is the type of the inputs?
- Does the accumulator saturate, or will it roll over?

Here is a sample unsigned accumulator to give you an idea of what you need to implement (based on this [source](http://www.alvie.com/zpuino/vhdl7.html)):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity accumulator is
  port (
    DIN:  in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    CLK:  in  std_logic;
    RST:  in  std_logic;
    DOUT: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
  );
end entity accumulator;

architecture behave of accumulator is

  signal acc_value : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

begin

  process(CLK)
  begin
    if rising_edge(CLK) then
      if RST='1' then
        acc_value <= (others => '0'); -- reset accumulated value to 0
      else
        acc_value <= std_logic_vector( unsigned(acc_value) + unsigned(DIN) );
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

  -- Assign output
  DOUT <= acc_value;

end behave;
```

To describe what this design does in words: Every clock cycle on the rising edge, the data input `DIN` is interpreted as an unsigned value, and added to the currently accumulated value `acc_value`. If the `RST` input is asserted, instead of accumulating the `DIN` input, the accumulated value is cleared back to 0.  The value of the accumulator is always presented on the output of the block, `DOUT`.

Based on what you are interfacing with, you might want to consider the following changes/modifications:

- Perhaps `DIN` should be `signed` or `unsigned` types instead of `std_logic_vector`. I actually recommend this, but it depends on how you are representing your values in other places of your design.
- `DOUT` could also be a `signed` or `unsigned` value instead of `std_logic_vector` - it depends your requirements.
- In this case, `acc_value`, the accumulated value register, will rollover if the values accumulated get too high. Maybe you want to generate an error condition when this happens, or perform a check to ensure that you saturate at the maximum value of `acc_value` instead.
- `acc_value` need not be the same width as `DIN` -- it could be twice as wide (or whatever your requirements are). The wider it is, the more you can accumulate before the rollover condition occurs.